# Conversion of cartesian momenta to generalized ones

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism

The cartesian kinetic energy for a particle in $\mathbf R^3$ is
$$\mathcal T=\dfrac{1}{2}m||\mathbf x||^2=\dfrac{1}{2}m(\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2).$$

Knowing that momentum conjugate to $\square$ is
$$p_{\square}=\dfrac{\partial\mathcal T}{\partial\dot\square},$$
$\dot\square$ can be isolated in terms of $p_\square$ and so the KE from before can be expressed in terms of one of the Hamiltonian's natural variable, i.e, $p_k$, like this:
$$\mathcal T=\dfrac{1}{2m}(p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2).$$

Now say we can relate $\mathbf x$ to some generalized coordinates $\mathbf q$ like
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&x=x(q_1,q_2,q_3)\\
&y=y(q_1,q_2,q_3)\\
&z=z(q_1,q_2,q_3)
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Is there any way to find
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&p_x=p_x(\mathbf q,p_{q_1},p_{q_2},p_{q_3})\\
&p_y=p_y(\mathbf q,p_{q_1},p_{q_2},p_{q_3})\\
&p_z=p_z(\mathbf q,p_{q_1},p_{q_2},p_{q_3})
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
so that we get the generalized kinetic energy simply substituing the previous relations instead of isolating $\dot x_k$ in terms of $\dot q_k$ and then in terms of generalized momenta and substituing?